# Update Visual Studio 15 Preview

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017

Currently I have the Visual Studio 15 Preview 4 on my PC. Is there a way to update to the new released Preview 5?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/visual-studio-15-preview-5-now-available/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the FAQ [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/visual-studio-15-FAQ):

> Can I install Preview 5 with if I already installed Previews 4, 3, 2
>   or 1?
>
> You must uninstall all previous releases of Visual Studio "15" before
>   you try Preview 5. Follow these steps to uninstall preview versions:
>
> If you have Preview 4 installed or used the light-weight installer to
>   install Preview 1, 2, or 3, you must remove Visual Studio by using the
>   Visual Studio Installer.   Launch “Microsoft Visual Studio Installer”.
>   Uninstall the build from the Installer.   Uninstall any previous
>   Classic Visual Studio “15” builds from Preview 1, 2, or 3.
>   Right-click “uninstall” from the start menu, or use "Uninstall a
>   program" from Control Panel.